# upload image to facebook group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading, image-upload

Could anyone point me to some code dealing with uploading an image to a group via group post?

I have found some code here:

```
//IF FILE UPLOAD
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
     && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
   {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
       $error .= "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else{
       echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
       echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
       echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
       echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";    
       //facebook part below
       $args = array('message' => $_GET['title']);
       $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
       $data = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID/photos', 'post', $args);
       $entry->details = $data['id'];
    }
}
```

Since it says /photos i figured it would only place the image that was uploaded into the photos tab within the group. However, i would just like it to post it on the wall  of the group itself (using me if needed as the poster so no log in is needed).

However i am wondering what other code needs to be in place in order for it to work correctly with FB API since i am unable to find examples for a group? And what code i need in order to use the $_FILES["file"] command ([this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
$data = $facebook->api('/GROUP_ID/feed', 'post', $args);
```

Try looking [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) also.